# PAGINATION : Show First and Last Page at pager / toolbar grid view

Tags: magento-1, toolbar, pager

at the moment my pager at grid view is like this " 1 2 3 4 5 >" on page 5 it's "< 5 6 7 8 9 >". [See Screenshot](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3511/wifyjl3c_png.htm)

How can I edit my pager.phtml template to get a result like this : " 1 2 3 4 5 Last >" or "First < 5 6 7 8 9 > Last"

I want to show the first and last page on my pager.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to dig in the code and find where and why the canShowFirst() and canShowLast() logic was failing

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar on line 815:

```
    $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
        ->setShowPerPage(false)
        ->setShowAmounts(false)
        ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
        ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
        ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
        ->setFrameLength(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame'))
        ->setJump(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip'))
        ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
```

setJump() was using an admin setting in System > Config > General > Design > Pagination. 'pagination_frame_skip' was empty, but when i echoed it in pager.phtml it gave a value of 0.  Seems like the core code should check the value of the store config before setting the jump, but that neither here nor there.  I set the value in the admin to 5(which is the default setting in Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager, but Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar was overriding it) and all the canShow logic was now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\pager.phtml
and find:
lines which contains $this->canShowFirst() and line $this->canShowLast().

Below them you will find html to edit to change

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick answer. But my pager doesn't show first and last. how can I activate this option first?

Comment: How many pages do you have?

Comment: You should see "go to the last" when you have more then 5 pages. Just check if you use app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\pager.phtml. If you use your own template copy/paste the code with $this->canShowFirst() and line $this->canShowLast().

Comment: In my category there are 9027 products. Here's a link: http://shop.maschinenring.de/produkte.html?manufacturer=702
I use the standard magento toolbar and pager template but I've copied it in my theme folder

Comment: Does your template contains if ($this->canShowFirst())?

Comment: At /frontend/theme/template/page/html/pager.phtml :
    <?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>
        <li><a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">1</a></li>
        <?php endif;?>
...

That's the original magento-template. I think I have to "enable" this function "canShowFirst"  - I don't know?

Comment: This function should work without enabling. Try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to edit **pager.phtml** template file. Default template file is `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\pager.phtml.`

Find

`<?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>`

and replace with

`<?php if ($this->getFrameStart() > 1): ?>`

---

Find

`<?php if ($this-> canShowLast()): ?>`

Replace with

`<?php if ($this->getFrameEnd() < $this->getLastPageNum()): ?>`

---

Now the `first` and `last` button will show when nedded.